# Launching System Processes From Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want users to upload pics and then have a background process that converts them to an animated gif. For right now I'd just like to fork a sys process and let a script do the processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read of this article: [6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://zhangxh.net/programming/ruby/6-ways-to-run-shell-commands-in-ruby/)

Pick one of those methods and use it in your controller.

If you want anything moderately complex (ie reading output from `stderr`) you'll need to use a gem - likely `open4`.

Comment: This is some good info on how to do it in Ruby. In Rails, there are some other options, looks like Delayed Job might fit the bill. http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job. Getting something to run on Heroku might be impossible.